# Error with OpenCV imshow in anaconda environment

Tags: opencv, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying to use imshow in conda, but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Online_fordprop.py", line 33, in 
> cv2.imshow("test", frame)
> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv-suite_1535558553474/work/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:632: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

I've seen this error in other threads and I've tried everything in the comments, but it doesn't work. I have opencv-contrib-python     4.4.0.44 in the conda environment, but I suspect that there's another OpenCV version in the computer because when I run

```
import cv2
cv2.__version__
```

in an environment with no OpenCV libraries, it returns 3.4.2.

Any idea how I can get rid of that opencv background or how to make the imshow command work?

*Update*: I have run sudo apt-get purge '*opencv*' and so I can no longer use import cv2 when the environment has no OpenCV libraries, but I still get the same error explained above.

Comment: Usually it's installed from `apt`. In that case, you should be able to see it returned by this  command `apt search python3-opencv | grep installed`

Comment: It returns: 'WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.'

Comment: Do you know how to create a conda environment? If you know it, then create a new anaconda environment, then install `opencv` and `contrib` the problem will be solved. If you don't know I  will write as an answer.

Comment: Creating a new environment and installing opencv-python by pip worked. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new environment and installing opencv-python by pip worked.